# positioning using for loop count

Tags: javascript, for-loop, coordinates

I have a javascript where I am giving a position to a number of objects being created.

Say the number of objects is 120.

Each object has an X and Y coordinate as pixels.

Im trying to make it so the first 30 objects are on one row, then move to the next row for each 30 objects.

Im wondering is there an easy way of doing this. I cant seem to get my tiny head around it.

heres a similar thing for just running across one row:

```
for(i=0, i>arguments.length, i++){

var offset = i + 50; 

createobject('object1, x, 100+offset, y, 100);

}
```

is there some way of dividing i by 30 to add to the y offset?

Comment: Just make a nested loop iterating over x and y separately. Makes it easier to reason about.

Answer (score 2):

here is the way to go,

```
var y = 0;
for (i = 0, i > arguments, i++){

    var offset = i + 50;
    if (i%30 == 0) y++;

    createobject('object1, x, 100+offset, y, 100);
}
```

The y gets incremented for each time the 'i' reaches the 30th count.